# Manim can't compile Latex "latex error converting to dvi."

Tags: manim

I tried compiling the following code:

```
class I3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        z = Tex("e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)")
        self.add(z)
        self.wait(5)
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: latex error converting to dvi. See log output above or the log file: media/Tex/d946638dc8ff7097.log
```

The .log file mentioned is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=latex 2022.7.16)  17 JUL 2022 18:20
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./media/Tex/d946638dc8ff7097.tex
(media/Tex/d946638dc8ff7097.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 3
L3 programming layer <2022-06-16> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone
\standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preview\preview.sty
Package: preview 2017/04/24 13.1 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/luatex85\luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preview\prtightpage.def
\PreviewBorder=\dimen139
)
\pr@snippet=\count196
\pr@box=\box51
\pr@output=\toks18
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2022/06/06 3.76 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count197
\U@D=\dimen140
\l@unhyphenated=\language79
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count198
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'canadian' set to \l@english
(babel)             (\language0). Reported on input line 102.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'australian' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73). Reported on input line 105.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'newzealand' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73). Reported on input line 108.
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel/locale/en\babel-english.tex
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for english
(babel)             from babel-en.ini. Reported on input line 11.
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks19
\inpenc@posthook=\toks20
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks21
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count266
\leftroot@=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count268
\DOTSCASE@=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count270
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count271
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count272
\dspbrk@lvl=\count273
\tag@help=\toks22
\row@=\count274
\column@=\count275
\maxfields@=\count276
\andhelp@=\toks23
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks24
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks25
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/doublestroke\dsfont.sty
Package: dsfont 1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman fonts
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tipa\tipa.sty
Package: tipa 2002/08/08 TIPA version 1.1
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
(C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tipa\t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
Now handling font encoding T3 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T3
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmss on input line 3
57.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\t1lmss.fd
File: t1lmss.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 11
2.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
))) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/relsize\relsize.sty
Package: relsize 2013/03/29 ver 4.1
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/jknappen\mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup6
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fundus-calligra\calligra.sty
Package: calligra 2012/04/10 v1.9 LaTeX package calligra
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/wasysym\wasysym.sty
Package: wasysym 2020/01/19 v2.4 Wasy-2 symbol support package
\symwasy=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `wasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/wasy/m/n --> U/wasy/b/n on input line 93.
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ragged2e\ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2021/12/15 v3.1 ragged2e Package
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip52
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip53
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip54
\CenteringRightskip=\skip55
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip56
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip57
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip58
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip59
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip60
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip61
\CenteringParindent=\skip62
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip63
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip64
\JustifyingParindent=\skip65
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/physics\physics.sty
Package: physics 
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty (C:\Program Fil
es\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-06-16 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count277
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box55
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box56
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count278
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count279
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count280
))
Package: xparse 2022-06-22 L3 Experimental document command parser
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 227.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex-dev/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
) (C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2022/06/23 v3.0f Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count281
)
\MT@toks=\toks26
\MT@tempbox=\box57
\MT@count=\count282
LaTeX Info: Redefining \noprotrusionifhmode on input line 1045.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \leftprotrusion on input line 1046.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rightprotrusion on input line 1056.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 1234.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen150
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1858.
\MT@listname@count=\count283

(C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype-pdftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2022/06/23 v3.0f Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)

LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 900.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 900.
\MT@outer@space=\skip66
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.
(C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2022/06/23 v3.0f microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
No file d946638dc8ff7097.aux.
\openout1 = `d946638dc8ff7097.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T3+cmr on input line 24
.
(C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tipa\t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `item' on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `toc' on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `eqnum' on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Applying patch `footnote' on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Generating DVI output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: No font expansion.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
(C:\Users\selae\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.27 e^
       {i   heta}=\cos( heta)+i\sin(    heta) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8382 strings out of 478352
 131308 string characters out of 2846893
 474783 words of memory out of 3000000
 26693 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 478062 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,2n,77p,1025b,170s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
```

This code actually does work:

```
class I3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        z = Tex("LaTeX")
        self.add(z)
        self.wait(5)
```

Which makes me believe there are some missing packages, after some digging around I've seen some people suggest to ran `latex tex_template.tex` in the manimlib folder but I couldn't find this folder anywhere on my computer. What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention whether you are using manimgl or the community maintained version of Manim, but judging from the error I guess you are running the community maintained version (`from manim import *`).

In that case, `Tex` renders TeX in normal mode, and `MathTex` inserts your string in an `align*`-environment (and thus, in math mode). This is what the error towards the end of your log file complains about:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.27 e^
       {i   heta}=\cos( heta)+i\sin(    heta)
```

This actually also reveals a second problem with your code, given that `\t` has been replaced by spaces: `\` is a special character in Python strings; to actually write a `\` you need to escape it by writing `\\` -- or, alternatively, use a raw string by putting a `r` before your string.

TL;DR, this is what you want:

```py
class I3(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        z = MathTex(r"e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)")
        self.add(z)
        self.wait(5)
```